# Есть ли возможность менять IP локальной машины из программы?

Tags: c#, ip, visual-studio-2013

Все пишется в VS 2013 на C#. Собственно сабж. Нужно менять ip локального компа прямо из программы, есть ли такая возможность? На локальной машине две сетевых карты.

Comment: Навскидку простой вариант: вызвать через `Process.Start` команду netsh, передав ей необходимые аргументы (имя адаптера, ip, маску и т.д.).

Comment: Вот тут пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/760611/4712334

Comment: А других вариантов нет?

Comment: вариант посложнее, через WMI: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6975/SwitchNetConfig-Laptop-users-quickly-switch-networ

Answer (score 1):

А вы пробовали гуглить?

Вот сдесь человек дал тупо весь нужный код которым можно изменять любые настройки нетворка. DNS, Ip и другое.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209779/how-can-you-change-network-settings-ip-address-dns-wins-host-name-with-code